# Detect loop in linked list (Floyd cycle finding algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

I have written this code Floyd Cycle finding algorithm. The methods I have used are `createLoop()` , `doesLoopExist()`, `lengthOfLoop()` and `insert()`.
I want to optimise this code and improve using advanced C++.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
  struct Node
  {
    T data;
    Node * next;
    Node(T value) : data(value), next(nullptr) {}
  };
  Node *head;

public:
  LinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}
  ~LinkedList();
  void insert(T);
  void createLoop(int);
  bool doesLoopExist();
  int lengthOfLoop();
};

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(T data)
{
  Node *node = new Node(data);
  Node *tmp = head;
  if(tmp == nullptr)
  {
    head = node;
  }
  else
  {
    while(tmp->next != nullptr)
    {
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = node;
  }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::createLoop(int n)
{
  Node *tmp = head;
  Node *tail = head;
  for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
  {
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }

  while(tail->next != nullptr)
  {
    tail = tail->next;
  }
  tail->next = tmp;
}

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::doesLoopExist()
{
  Node *slowPtr = head;
  Node *fastPtr = head;

  while(slowPtr && fastPtr && fastPtr->next)
  {
    slowPtr = slowPtr->next;
    fastPtr = fastPtr->next->next;

    if(slowPtr == fastPtr)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

template <class T>
int LinkedList<T>::lengthOfLoop()
{
  int count = 0, loopExist = 0;
  Node *slowPtr = head;
  Node *fastPtr = head;
  while(slowPtr && fastPtr && fastPtr->next)
  {
    slowPtr = slowPtr->next;
    fastPtr = fastPtr->next->next;

    if(slowPtr == fastPtr)
    {
      loopExist = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(loopExist)
  {
    fastPtr = fastPtr->next;
    count++;
    while(slowPtr != fastPtr)
    {
      fastPtr = fastPtr->next;
      count++;
    }
    return count;
  }
  return 0;
}

template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
  Node *tmp = nullptr;
  while(head)
  {
    tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete tmp;
  }
  head = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
  LinkedList<char> ll1;
  ll1.insert('p');
  ll1.insert('r');
  ll1.insert('o');
  ll1.insert('g');
  ll1.insert('r');
  ll1.insert('a');
  ll1.insert('m');
  ll1.insert('m');
  ll1.insert('e');
  ll1.insert('r');

  int nodeNumber = 5;
  //Node number starts from 1

  ll1.createLoop(nodeNumber);
  bool result = ll1.doesLoopExist();
  if(result == true)
  {
    std::cout <<"Loop exist in the Linked List\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout <<"Loop does not exist in the Linked List\n";
  }

  int len = ll1.lengthOfLoop();
  std::cout << "Length of Loop is " << len <<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- DRY. The first loop of `lengthOfLoop` is literally identical to `doesLoopExist`. Replace it with

  ```
      loopExist = doesLoopExist();
  ```

  This also hints that `doesLoopExist` should be `Node * doesLoopExist()`, and return *a* node on the loop or `nullptr`.
- The destructor invokes UB when applied to the list with a loop. At the end of the loop the `next` pointer points to an already deleted node.
- `insert` should be better called `append`.